# Can I initialize Dictionary Values automatically?

Tags: c#, dictionary, initialization

Let's say I want to store my data as a bunch of named lists.

I really like how with `Dictionary`, you can do:

```
myDictionary["SomeKey"] = new List<string>{ "SomeString" };
```

But unfortunately, I cannot safely do:

```
myDictionary["SomeKey"].Add("SomeString");
```

Because if the `List` at `SomeKey` has not yet been initialized, I'll get a null reference exception.

So everytime I alter a value in the dictionary, I have to do:

```
if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey("SomeKey")) myDictionary["SomeKey"] = new List<string>();
```

Before I can safely add to each list. It looks ugly and distracts from non-boilerplate code. I also duplicate code in several places (accessing `SomeKey` several times when all I want to say is "add this element to the list at `SomeKey`, regardless of whether it is empty or not").

There is basically no reason why I would want uninitialized values in my `Dictionary`. If it was an array of `List`, I would have looped through every element beforehand and initialized each member; I can't do this with `Dictionary` because I don't know what the keys will be in advance.

Is there a more concise syntax for saying, "access the value at this key, and if it is null, then initialize it"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is, but you could do it as an extension method if you wanted. Something like

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static SafeAdd(this Dictionary<string,List<string>> obj, string key, string val)
    {
        // your example code
    }
}
```

then you could do `myDictionary.SafeAdd("somekey","somestring");`

Comment: Is it possible to extend the `this[key]` indexer to check if the value requested is null?

Comment: the indexer doesn't look like it's virtual when I tried subclassing, but you could always create your own implementation of IDictionary<string,List<string>> that does it the way you want, just more typing to do so.